# How to extract lines from a file using parametres in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a log file containes all information.

```
2017-09-21 02:01:11,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] INFO   - Inbound Message
...
...
2017-09-21 09:01:11,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] INFO   - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 6044
Address: http://localhost/serveur/Service?wsdl
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
...
2017-09-21 12:01:11,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] INFO   - Inbound Message
...
```

I want to extract only information between 2 dates. For exemple, if I want information between 2017-09-21 09.. and 2017-09-21 12 I would have something like this:

```
./script.sh 2017-09-21 09 2017-09-21 12
# $1 = 2017-09-21
# $2 = 09
# $3 = 2017-09-21
# $4 = 12
# $1 & 2 are date and hour to begin extract
# $3 & 4 are date and hour to finish extract
```

my script is like this. I don't have knowledge in shell programming but I tried to do this. Unfortunatly it doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash

beginLine = "$1 $2"
finishLine = "$3 $4"

while read fileLog.log
do
    if($fileLog.log grep beginLine)
         echo $fileLog.log >> extractedlog.log
    fi
    if($fileLog.log grep finishLine)
         < extractedLog.log;
    fi
done
exit 0;
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: This is not `bash` syntax

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/2017-09-21 09/{a=1};a;/2017-09-21 12/{exit}' input
2017-09-21 09:01:11,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] INFO   - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 6044
Address: http://localhost/serveur/Service?wsdl
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
...
2017-09-21 12:01:11,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] INFO   - Inbound Message
```

More alternatives found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180663/how-to-select-first-occurrence-between-two-patterns-including-them)

Answer (score 2):

Short **sed** approach (matching a range of patterns `/.../,/.../`):

```
sed -n '/2017-09-21 09/,/2017-09-21 12/p' logfile
```

**----------**

The same can be done with **awk** (even shorter):

```
awk '/2017-09-21 09/,/2017-09-21 12/' logfile
```

Comment: And to quit the process after matching 2017-09-21 12 I should use the /q that is it?

Comment: @Chinovski, nope, not in this case. `q` should not be added here

Comment: @tripleee, all extended cases should have been described and elaborated in the question. Anybody could invent the more and more extended conditions